# Reverse colors in color scheme

Tags: color, legending

I have a `SwatchLegend` with a color scheme:

```
SwatchLegend[10, {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"}, 
 LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 16, Bold, Black, FontFamily -> "Arial"}, 
 LegendMarkerSize -> 16]
```

How can I reverse the colors in the color scheme?

Comment: `SwatchLegend[ColorData[10][#]&/@Reverse[Range[7]], {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"}, 
 LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 16, Bold, Black, FontFamily -> "Arial"}, 
 LegendMarkerSize -> 16]`

Comment: Thanks N.J.: Nice solution!

Comment: Somewhat related: [(106152)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/106152/121)

Comment: Another [related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21587).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is to go to [`ColorData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorData.html). That `10` means `ColorData[10]`, so you can do this:

```
With[{divs = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"}}, 
 SwatchLegend[
  ColorData[10][Length[divs] - # + 1] & /@ Range@Length[divs],
  divs, 
  LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 16, Bold, Black, FontFamily -> "Arial"}, 
  LegendMarkerSize -> 16]
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know I can access the color data like that :).

Comment: An alternative is to have `Range[]` generate the indices in reverse: `With[{divs = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"}}, SwatchLegend[ColorData[10] /@ Range[Length[divs], 1, -1], divs, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 16, Bold, Black, FontFamily -> "Arial"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 16]]`

Answer (score 5):

**You don't have to *reverse colors in color scheme*.**

Instead, you can simply `Reverse` your label list and use `"ReversedRow"` layout:

```
SwatchLegend[10, Reverse@{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"}, 
 LegendLayout -> {"ReversedRow", 1}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, Bold, Black, FontFamily -> "Arial"}, 
 LegendMarkerSize -> 30]
```

[image]

Similarly, for `PointLegend` and `LineLegend`:

```
PointLegend[10, Reverse@{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"}, 
 LegendLayout -> {"ReversedRow", 1}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, Bold, Black, FontFamily -> "Arial"}, 
 LegendMarkers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", 30}]
```

[image]

```
LineLegend[10, Reverse@{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"}, 
 LegendLayout -> {"ReversedRow", 1}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, Bold, Black, FontFamily -> "Arial"}, 
 LegendMarkerSize -> 50]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks kglr, did not discover this option yet, good to know :)

Comment: @holistic, my pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"};

SwatchLegend[
 ColorData[10, "ColorList"][[Length@data ;; 1 ;; -1]], data,
 LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1},
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 16, Bold, Black, FontFamily -> "Arial"},
 LegendMarkerSize -> 16]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you eldo!